# C++ OpenGL Nothing is rendering when attempting supersampling

Tags: c++, opengl, antialiasing, fbo

I'm attempting to have SSAA featured in my scene. Previously, I have setup the entire scene as an FBO, and it works fine (it renders perfectly on my screen). However as soon as I try to apply SSAA to it, the screen is always black, and I'm unsure why. I've followed a tutorial based on iOS but was fairly simple to copy to windows which can be found [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/iphone-3d-programming/9781449388133/ch06s08.html)
 However as I said when trying a similar technique to that it doesnt work. I understand the theory/concept of SSAA but cannot seem to get it to work. Any help I'd really appreciate it as I can't find much material on it (it is mostly on MSAA or other A.A. techniques)

***FBO Initialization***

```
void InitSSAAFBO()
{
    // Create the on-screen FBO.

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
        GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
        GL_RENDERBUFFER,
        fboColTex);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &bigColour);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, bigColour);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8,
        windowWidth * supersamplingLevel, windowHeight * supersamplingLevel);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &bigDepth);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, bigDepth);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24,
        windowWidth * supersamplingLevel, windowHeight * supersamplingLevel);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboBig);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboBig);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
        GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
        GL_RENDERBUFFER,
        bigColour);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
        GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
        GL_RENDERBUFFER,
        bigDepth);

    // Create a texture object and associate it with the big FBO.

    glGenTextures(1, &offscreenTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, offscreenTexture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, windowWidth * supersamplingLevel, windowHeight * supersamplingLevel, 0,
        GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, offscreenTexture, 0);

    GLenum demoFBOStatus = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

    if (demoFBOStatus != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {

        fboOkay = false;
        cout << "Could not successfully create framebuffer object to render texture!" << endl;

    }
    else {

        fboOkay = true;
        cout << "FBO successfully created" << endl;
    }

    // Unbind FBO for now! (Plug main framebuffer back in as rendering destination)
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

***Rendering***

```
void display(void) {

    //Bind Large FBO
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboBig);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, bigColour);
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth * supersamplingLevel, windowHeight * supersamplingLevel);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    DrawScene();


    //Bind small/Onscreen FBO
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, fboColTex);

    glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glUseProgram(fboShader);
    glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, offscreenTexture);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

***fboShader (Vertex Shader)***

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoords;

out vec2 TexCoords;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
    TexCoords = texCoords;
}
```

***fboShader (Fragment Shader)***

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D screenTexture;

void main()
{ 
    color = texture(screenTexture, TexCoords);
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't make sense. There is no such thing as an "onscreen FBO". There is also lots of unnecessary code regarding render buffers which you later replace from textures. However, what you _seemingly_ are trying to do here is just _downsampling_, not _supersampling_.

Comment: Oic...do you have any recommendations for a good quality supersampling tutorial?

Comment: What do you even mean by superasmpling?What you might want to do in GL is a multisampled color buffer in combination with per-sample shading. But it is totally unclear to me if that is what you actually want, and why you would want it.

Comment: SSAA (render scene to offscreen texture a higher-than-screen resolution. It is then rendered to screen and each "on-screen pixel" hasa number of associated "sub-pixels" in the off-screen texture. And I want/need to do it as it is an assignment and my lecturer has given us no material on it at all :( so any help really is appreciated.

Comment: Well, GPUs do have supprt for supersampling, but what you describe is not that. You describe simple downsampling (which might or might not be considered supersampling, depending on who you ask, and in which context). In general,  real supersampling is more flexible, in that the sample locations are not fixed to an uniform grid as you get with downsampling.

Comment: Oic....my lecturer has mentioned using a pixel shader to sample multiple texels and output the colours to the screen...not sure if that clarifies what hes on about?

Comment: Well, that is just downsampling.